# SwiftUI: Value of type ‘some view’ has no member ‘presentation’

Tags: swiftui

[image]

Do you face this error `Value of type 'some View' has no member 'presentation'`?

What is the solution?

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Cupcake Corner"))
.presentation($showingConfirmation) {
   Alert(title: Text("Thank you!"), message: Text(confirmationMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `presentation` modifier you can use `sheet` which will present a modal view.

However, it looks like you're trying to present an `Alert`. You can do it with the `.alert` modifier.

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingConfirmation) {
    // ...
}
```

Useful links:

- [Alerts, Action Sheets, Modals and Popovers in SwiftUI](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/07/24/alerts-actionsheets-modals-and-popovers-in-swiftui/)